# Filters on a topological space

Tags: general-topology, filters

I have a very simple question regarding the characterization of compactness by way of ultrafilters on a topological space (i.e. a space is compact iff every ultrafilter converges to at least one point in the space). Do the ultrafilters in question need to be subsets of the topology? That is, let $\langle X, \tau \rangle$ be a topological space; in order to characterize compactness by way of ultrafilters, do I need to consider the ultrafilters as subsets of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ or a subsets of $\tau$?

If the latter, does that mean that when characterizing a topology by way of a system of neighborhoods, I need the ultrafilter to be a set of (unions of) neighborhoods?

Comment: Compactness implies that all ultrafilters (with elements of $P(X)$) converge. To test compactness it is enough to check that all filters of the poset of closet sets has a cluster point. In fact, assume that $U_i$, for $i\in I$ is an open cover of $X$ without finite subcover, and that every filter of the poset of closed subsets of $X$ has a cluster point and that $X$. Consider the filter of the poset of closed subsets of $X$ generated by the finite intersections of the $U_i$. Let $x$ be a cluster point. There is a $U_i$ such that $x\in U_i$. But then $U_i\cap U_I^c=\emptyset$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A filter in this characterisation of compactness is just a collection of subsets of $X$, i.e. a filter in the lattice $\mathscr{P}(X)$. An ultrafilter is a maximal filter in this lattice. The topology comes in because we consider the closures of the filter sets and get a family of closed sets with FIP and (if with intersection) these correspond to open covers via complements, etc.

The property that every open ultrafilter converges (i.e. we consider filters and maximal filters in the lattice of open sets (so in $\mathscr{T}$, or $\tau$ as you use) also has been considered and is equivalent to the property that $X$ is $H$-closed (a property related to compactness, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/732268/4280), or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-closed_space), etc. Full proofs can be found in 
*Extensions and Absolutes of Hausdorff Spaces* by Porter and Woods.